# Greater than or equal constraint not working correctly

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have a `UIView` with 3 `UIView`s inside, I need every `UIView` to define it's one height depending of its contents and at the same time, the parent view should change its size depending of its children. But I'm having this issue:

[image: Not working properly]

I need the first `UIView` from the second column's height to always stick to its content and leave the remaining space in the end of the column. In other words, what I want is the second column's first `UIView` to shrink.

Here's my IB, the `greater than or equal` constraints are not working as I expected (I highlighted the relevant constraints):

[image: Interface Builder]

I've tried changing priorities but nothing's working, hope you can help me out, thanks.

EDIT: I forgot to show what's going on inside each `UIView`. The image might be present or not so if it's not I remove it and "pass" the `UIView`'s height responsibility to the label, just that:

[image: Inside each UIView]

Comment: Can you change the background colour of the labels to something other than white. Just to see where the label is and where the outer view is.

Comment: The label container ends where the text ends, the space between the label and the end of the view is empty

Comment: I mean at runtime. With white on white you can't see what the layout is doing. Change them to red or something just to see whats happening when you run it.

Comment: I mean as runtime as well, already checked that and the container fits the text exactly

Answer (score 5):

A greater than or equal constraint will always be as small as possible while satisfying all other constraints. So in this case it is correct...

The reason it is correct is because the label you are using will allow its frame to grow beyond its content.

To fix this you need to change the `content hugging priority` on the two labels on the right hand side.

To do this, select the label and go to the measurements section in Interface Builder property inspector.

Near the bottom you will see "Content Hugging Priority". Change the `vertical` value of this to `1000` (a.k.a. required).

This will tell the label to keep its frame as small as possible to fit the content. And so, the greater than constraint will have to be taller to satisfy this.

Comment: Your answer makes complete sense but it's not working, I have some logic going on inside the `UIView`s so maybe that's what preventing it to work properly, I'm gonna update the post now

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by extending the labels to the bottom of each `UIView`, now the `UIView`s have no excuse to expand more than the label's height.